# what's Clion's default compiler?

Tags: c++, clion

I'm wondering who knows what's the default compilers of CLION?
I have been googled but found no information.
I am using mac.
Is the compiler Clang or GCC?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: IIRC, the command `g++` (and `gcc`) are aliases for the Clang compiler on OSX, unless you explicitly install GCC.

Comment: But any IDE could bundle their own compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is configurable and controlled via the build system, CMake.

Go to Toolchains in CLion preferences and look under the CMake settings on the lower right.

[image]

To get more details, you can go to that location and ask for the exact version on the command line:

```
$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
$ cpp --version
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 2):

It says it there, right on the [front page](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) (for CLion 1.1, released in August):

> The default debugger on OS X is now LLDB (GDB is still configurable). Enjoy it together with the same powerful features and UI views that are available for GDB.

I can only assume your google-fu needs a bit of maintenance :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am a newbee to cpp so I didn't know the terminology 'LLDB'.